# First-letter pseudo-element not working properly with quote sign in CSS

Tags: css, pseudo-element, blockquote

I am trying to style a `pull-quote` div tag. I want to style the quote mark `"` so it is bigger than the rest of the statement.

I thought of using the `first-letter` pseudo-element. However when I did so, it did not work properly. Here are the cases I tried:

If I wrote the sentence like this: `"This is a test`,(with no spaced between the `"`and the`T` then both the `"T`appear big.

If I wrote it with a space between them, none of them get bigger.

My question is: is there a way to get the `"` only to be bigger?

Here is the html code I used: `<div class="pullquote-right">"this is a test</div>`

The css:

```
.pullquote-right {
display: inline-block;
max-width: 350px;
float: right;
padding-left: 15px;
margin-left: 25px;
border-left: #3b5998;
border-left-width: thick;
border-left-style: solid;   
font-style: italic;
color: darkgray;
font-size:115%;}

.pullquote-right::first-letter {font-size: 200%;}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks BoltClock for the edit. it definitely helped me to understand more about choosing tags.

Comment: please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help)it will be useful to lift your content quality up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option would be to use the ::before and ::after pseudo elements.

```css
.quote::before,
.quote::after {
  content: "\0022";
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: green;
  vertical-align: -.3em;
}
```

```html
<p class="quote">This is a great quote</p>
```

Comment: Thanks haltersweb. this answer helped too.

Answer (score 1):

The first-letter pseudo class refers to the first letter and the punctuation directly preceding it. Reference: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter

I think the easiest way to do what you want might be to put a span tag around the punctuation you want to make bigger and style that from the css.

Or you can check out this work-around: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/simple-and-nice-blockquote-styling/

Comment: Thank you very much Rose, for both the reference and the example.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up combining the two answers to be able to use the `div` tag and not neet to add extre `<p></p>`as follows:

```css
.pullquote-left {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 350px;
  float: left;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  border-left: #3b5998;
  border-left-width: thick;
  border-left-style: solid;
  font-style: italic;
  color: darkgray;
  font-size: 110%;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #888888;
  text-align: center;
}
.pullquote-left::before {
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  content: "\201C";
}
```

```html
<div class="pullquote-left">This is the final result.</div>
```